Help me identify Italy frame
The frame has a Campagnolo carriage.  The continuation of the upper pipe is also characteristic.  I would be grateful for any advice.

The text on the frame is extraneous, ignore it.

Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. It is good to crop the figure you upload, the large black margins are really excessive here. Did you perhaps make a screenshot of a photo or something? Png is normally not used for photos as it takes too much space. In that case it is best to upload the photo itself, not the screenshot. Or rotate your phone before making the screenshot.

Cropping is fixed now.

Sergio: what are the other possible translations for "carriage"? I'm not certain what you are referring to. The frame is an early Aluminium from before the time removable derailleur hangers became obligitory. 1989-1994?

Did Campagnolo ever released a MTB groupset?

@Renaud they did, in the early 1990s. They were called Euclid, Centaur, Icarus and Record, if i am not mistaken. They were not exactly a huge success though.
